# debian restart with crontab if file exists

Tags: php, shell, debian, cron

I have this scipt:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
 if [ -f /opt/command/command.txt ]; then
    chmod 777 /opt/command/command.txt
    rm /opt/command/command.txt
    reboot
 fi
done
```

and in my crontab i have:

```
@reboot sh /root/reboot.sh
```

And the file is created with this php code:

```
$fh = fopen("/opt/command/command.txt", 'w');
fwrite($fh, "reboot");
fclose($fh);
```

so if i run `sh reboot.sh` manually, this code works.
But in the crontab, nothing happens.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is `PATH` set (`echo $PATH`) when the crontab runs the script?

Comment: @Sverri: you should stop posting other peoples answers in comments.

Comment: @cari Do you see the question mark at the end of my comment? Last I checked, answers do not have question marks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the way i was doing it.

I added to `/etc/sudoers` the line:

```
%www-dataALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

and in my php file  i am doing:

```
exec("sudo /sbin/reboot");
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your crontab has no PATH-variable set.
set PATH variable for the command sh or use the full path like /bin/sh

Comment: You should refrain from assuming stuff. If you need more information in order to answer a question then use the comments area to ask for more information.